# Need a javascript function to load new page

Tags: javascript

My site has English and Spanish versions of each page. The folder structure is identical for both, but all Spanish pages are under a /_spanish folder. For example:
/index.htm is English version
/_spanish/index.htm is Spanish version

I'd like to include a button on each page making it easy to swap languages.

The logic is:

onclick parse the full current page name

if it does not contain /_spanish/

insert /_spanish/ and go to that page e.g. go from http://example.com/index.htm to 
http://example.com/_spanish/index.htm

else (it does contain /_spanish/)

remove /_spanish and go to that page e.g. go from http://example.com/_spanish/index.htm to http://example.com/index.htm

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working - not the most elegant, but functional.

```
<button style="width:100px;height:100px;" onclick="myFunction()"></button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

  var host = location.hostname;
  var path = location.pathname;
  var n = path.indexOf('/_spanish');
  var len = path.length;

  if (n>-1) { 
     /* make the new page address without _spanish */

     var newpath = path.substr(10,len-9);   
     var newpage = '/'.concat(newpath);     
  }
  else {
    /* make the new page address with _spanish inserted*/
     var newpath = path.substr(10,len-9);
     var spa = "/_spanish/"; 
     var newpages= spa.concat(path);
     /*Replace double // that will occur in sub-directories */
     newpage = newpages.replace(/\/\//,"/");     
  }

  window.location.href = newpage;
  }
</script>
```